# PHP Iterate over Child's Child Efficiently

Tags: php, recursion

I have this code:

```
foreach($list as $id => $item_array) {
    if (($item_array['approved'] == 1) || $is_admin) {
        include('item.php');
    }
    $temp = $item_array;
    while(!empty($temp['child'])) {
        foreach($temp['child'] as $id => $item_array) {
            if (($item_array['approved'] == 1) || $is_admin) {
                include('item.php');
            }
        }
        if(empty($temp['child']['child'])) {
            unset($temp);
        }
    }
}
```

which functions but I'm going to need to duplicate the `while` block 5 times because my `item`s can have up to six levels. There must be a more efficient way to do this, right? (The `item.php` just outputs HTML based on the array values)

In the simplest form `$list` would be:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => Water
    [date] => 2018-05-14 13:24:22
    [content] => It's Good
    [approved] => 1
    [level] => 0
    [child] => Array([0] => Array(
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Hydrogen
                    [date] => 2017-05-07 15:12:14
                    [content] => Part air
                    [approved] => 1
                    [level] => 1)
                )
)
```

If needed I build `$list` with:

```
if($parent != -1) {
        $list[$parent]['child'][] = $this->build_list_array($id, $date, $content, $name, $approved, $level);
} else {
    $list[$id] = $this->build_list_array($id, $date, $content, $name, $approved, $level);
}
function build_comment_array($id, $date, $content, $name, $approved, $level) {
    return array('id' => $id,
                'name' => $name,
                'date' => $date,
                'content' => $content,
                'approved' => $approved,
                'level' => $level);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it recursively. Create a function (let's say, `iterateChildren(array)`) that iterates over the given array and when the *children* key is found you call `iterateChildren(item['children'])`.

This way you can have as many levels as you'd like, since the function calls itself at each level.

Be cautious, though, because with too many levels you may run out of memory.